# What does kpsewhich stand for?

Tags: texlive, kpathsea

I often have trouble remembering the name of the `kpsewhich` command. Maybe it would be easier for me to remember it, if I understand where the name come from, so the question is:

What does the `kpse` stand for?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**K**arl's **P**ath **SE**arch Library **WHICH**

Comment: Thank you! This will make it much easier to remember!

Comment: @david-carlisle what a bold answer ;-)

Comment: @muxoveji honestly, it doesn't help me to remember it any better! Why not a simpler name? Who is Karl by the way?

Comment: @SaeedAhadian Karl Berry who wrote the code and who has maintained texlive for the last few decades.

Answer (score 20):

As `info kpathsea` says (online manual [here](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html)), Kpathsea is a library for *path searching* (e.g., for very quickly locating a given `.sty` file in a set of potentially large TEXMF trees, *without* doing a recursive directory tree traversal every time a given file is needed; this is important when compiling LaTeX documents using several packages, themselves requiring other packages, possibly various font files, etc.).

This *path search* gives the `pathse` part, abbreviated as `pse`. The “which“ reminds of the Unix `which` utility, which tells you the path of the executable run for a given command, according to your PATH environment variable. For instance:

```
$ which find
/usr/bin/find
```

I believe the “k” stands for “Karl Berry”. :-)

## Complements

The comparison between `which` and `kpsewhich` goes further than that. As Unix shells often maintain a cache of executables present in directories of the PATH in order to offer efficient lookup for command completion, the Kpathsea library maintains a filename database (comprised of the `ls-R` files in each TEXMF tree) in order to offer similar fast lookup to TeX-related programs.

In Unix shells, the cache can often be updated with a hash command (`hash -r` in Bash, `rehash` in Zsh) when you've added or removed executables from your PATH and wish to refresh the cache without restarting your shell; for the Kpathsea library, the corresponding operation is done with `mktexlsr`, also known as `texhash`.

Finally, `which` looks up a given executable in the directories listed in PATH<sup>1</sup>, in some way similarly as `kpsewhich` for finding a TeX-related file using either on-disk lookup or only the filename database (it depends on whether the TEXMF tree is preceded with `!!` where it is used in `texmf.cnf`<sup>2</sup>). `kpsewhich` is more sophisticated than a typical `which` builtin, though, as it can return different results depending on what was given as `-progname`, has a notion of variables that can be set in `texmf.cnf`, can look up in-cache-only or on-disk depending on the per-directory-settings in `texmf.cnf`, etc.

---

**Footnotes**

1. In Bash and Zsh at least, it seems to really search the PATH: if you add a new executable to a directory of your PATH, the `which` builtin of these shells finds it right away without any need to run `hash -r` or `rehash` (this may not be the case for command completion).
2. See for instance `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` on Debian.